In iOS 17, custom fonts display as "Helvetica" and cannot be used
The app I'm working on downloads custom fonts from on-demand resources and integrates them with iOS. These fonts become accessible in the Settings > General > Fonts menu, and UIFontPickerViewController ensures their availability to other productivity apps like Freeform.
Initially, the app functioned well up to iOS 16. However, in iOS 17, there were occasional issues where the font name selected using UIFontPickerViewController would incorrectly appear as "Helvetica". Furthermore, the selected font failed to render, resulting in the default font being displayed instead. Occasionally, fonts that were normally visible in UIFontPickerViewController would suddenly disappear.
I've verified that the fonts were correctly installed on iOS. What other troubleshooting steps would you suggest? Below is the code responsible for downloading a font from an on-demand resource and integrating it with the system.
func installFont(_ font : Font, completion:@escaping((Bool, Error?)->())) {
    self.requestFont(font:font, onSuccess: {[weak self] in
    self?.registerFont(font) { (errs, success) in
        if success {
            if errs != nil {
                let err = errs.debugDescription
                completion(true, Error(code:err.code, message: err))
            }
            else
            {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, Error())
        }
    }}, progress: { (fraction) in
        Log.debug("downloading \(fraction)")
    }) { (error) in
        var msg = ""
        switch error.code {
            case NSBundleOnDemandResourceOutOfSpaceError:
                msg = "You don't have enough space available to download this resource."
            case NSBundleOnDemandResourceExceededMaximumSizeError:
                msg = "The bundle resource was too big."
            case NSBundleOnDemandResourceInvalidTagError:
                msg = "The requested tag does not exist."
            default:
                msg = "download failed"
        }
        completion(false, Error(code: error.code, message: msg))
    }
}

func requestFont(font: Font,
    onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void,
    progress: @escaping (Double) -> Void,
    onFailure: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) -> NSBundleResourceRequest? {
        let tag = font.tag
        let request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])
        request.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources { (available) in
            if available {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                request.beginAccessingResources { (error: Error?) in
                    if let error = error {
                        onFailure(error as NSError)
                        return
                    }
                    font.isFontAvailable = true
                    onSuccess()
                }
                let _ = request.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted, changeHandler: { (req, change) in
                    progress(request.progress.fractionCompleted)
                })
            }
        }
    return request
}

func registerFont(_ font : Font, completion:@escaping((CFArray?, Bool)->())) {
    let urls = font.fonts.map {($0.fontURL ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))}
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs(urls as CFArray, .persistent, true) { [weak self]
        (errors, success) -> Bool in
        if success {
            if let errs = errors as? NSArray {
                completion(errors, false)
                return false
            } else {
                completion(nil, true)
            }
            return true
        } else {
            completion(errors, false)
            return false
        }
    }
}


My first move here would be to rewrite all of that code using async/await. That way you can reason about the code! Completion handlers are so 2022. If, after that, you still can't figure it out and the code can be shown to be behaving correctly, file a bug with Apple; the fact that iOS 17 is the only place where there's an issue should make you suspicious that this may be Apple's fault.

I'll try that move too. Thanks for the advice.
